# Index error when looping over first column in a text file

Tags: python, function, file, for-loop

I have the following code

**Code Snippet**

```
def quiz(dr):
  print("===Quiz===")
  print("You have selected a question rating of: ", dr)
  question_count=0
  while question_count<4:
    with open('questions.txt','r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
        for line in reader:
          print(line[0])
          question_count=question_count+1
```

This prints the questions in the text file (all five of them), which happen to be index[0] of each line in the text file, but then produces an index out of range error

**Error**

```
 File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/task1/v7.py", line 135, in history
    print(line[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Text file contents**

```
Question1?,a,b,cario,d,e,3
Question2?,adolf,b,c,d,e,1
Question3?,a,b,c,d,e,1
Question4?,a,b,c,d,e,1
Question5?,a,b,c,d,e,1
```

Can anyone 
a) fix the error with a clear explanation as to what is wrong
b) Suggest an edit to the above function to make it more elegant/pythonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's probably an empty line somewhere (difficult to spot when it's on the end), so `csv` module issues an empty row. Empty rows are sometimes generated by writing the `csv` file improperly (forgetting to set binary mode for python 2, forgetting to add `newline=""` for python 3)

To count non-empty rows just forget your `for` loop and just do:

```
question_count = sum(1 for line in reader if line)
```

note that with this method, you have to rewind the file to get the contents. The alternative is to store the lines in a list first: `line = list(line)`. (code above still applies)

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest more elegant code for the above function.